# How can I save tweets of a user as images?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, python-twitter

There is a Twitter user who posts valuable stuff and I want to save his tweets **not as text but as images** (screenshots) just as you see it on your phone or computer.

I installed python-twitter and tweepy but I didn't find a solution in the docs and neither in communities so far.

Alternatively: Is there another way to save tweets in a kind of pretty, visually appealing way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're going to save Tweets as images, how will you deal with the compliance issue of deleting Tweets when the user deletes them? (section III.B of the Developer Agreement https://developer.twitter.com/en/developer-terms/agreement-and-policy)

Comment: I don't see why a tweet saved as text or as an image would make much difference for this rule.

Comment: If you’re only storing the Tweet Id and then hydrating or displaying at runtime then for a deleted Tweet you wouldn’t end up showing a deleted Tweet. For a long term stored image of a Tweet then you already have a picture so there is no rehydration to check if the data should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Using Selenium Webdriver to open the Twitter account page in the browser, then scrape the tweets and use a screenshot tool to make an image. This looping through all tweets.

Answer (score 2):

With those libraries you can only extract Twitter data. Those aren't image processing libraries. You will have to write your own logic how you want those pictures displayed.

Look into [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this site called **tweetcyborg.com** It converts any tweet into an image.

Comment: That's basically what I was looking for, except the limitation of not being able to use it automated. Do you know which software/framework they use? I could then write my own.